# Dual display detected but not working after startup 14.04

Tags: drivers, 14.04, ati, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Here's my situation--I've got an HP Envy laptop running 14.04 with an AMD A10 APU. Catalyst display dashboard and the works are installed. As the system boots up, it acknowledges the external display (via HDMI connection) and things seem normal. However, right after logging into the system, the external display shuts off. Even stranger, when I click on the display settings in Settings, it actually knows there's an external monitor attached. But no signal is going toward the external display. More frustratingly, when I log into the administrative version of the Catalyst Control Center, it won't even detect the second display. Anybody have anything on this? It's extremely frustrating and I really need two displays for my photo editing and I love using it for remote sessions. Thanks a bunch in advance.

By the way:
8 GB DDR3 RAM
1 TB HDD
Ubuntu 14.04
Latest AMD drivers for the A10 APU